# How do I make a text field's text the title of the next navigation controller using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, interface-builder

I have a text field in a UIViewController.  I have `@IBOutlet`ed the text field in the view controller's class.  I have a navigation controller that controls the next view controller declared in a different class, in a different .Swift file.  I want the text in the text field to be the title of the next view's navigation controller.

How can I do this in Swift?  I can't find an answer.  Do I control-drag from the text field into the class of the navigation controller that I want it to modify, not the class of the view controller that it's in?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to make it like this:

1. Create an outlet to your `textField` in your `FirstViewController`
2. Go to your `SecondViewController` and store a new variable `var customTitle = ""`
3. When you `segue` set the `customTitle`

So when you do:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecondViewController", sender: nil)
```

And then  in your `prepare` function you do set the `customTitle` to the `textField` value:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToSecondViewController" {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.customTitle = textField.text 
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things:  an error came back on the `secondVC.customTitle` line that made me put an exclamation point on the end of `textfield.text`.  Is this correct, or should it be a question mark?  Second, when I run it in the simulator and type text into the field, then press the button, i get a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error on the `let secondVC` line.  How can I fix this error?  I set the segue's identifier in the attributes inspector.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, I added `self.title = customTitle` in the `override func viewDidLoad` method on the second view controller.  Thanks.

Comment: @W.Cook, I created a sample project with the functionality for you to see how it works. Try it out and you´ll see how it works and then you can implement it in your project, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/efgc6rbpf95c3ru/WCook.zip?dl=0) is the project.

Comment: I downloaded and ran that.  I added a text field and used `textfield.text` and that works.  However, I have a navigation controller between my two views, because I want the second view to not autorotate.  When I did that in your project, I got that SIGABRT error.  Is there a way to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Okey, I have not implemented that in my sample project but you can use your project and just see have I did it in mine and do the same in yours. And if you need further help, zip the project and upload it to Dropbox or Google Drive and I´ll have a look at it.

Comment: You seem to have zipped the `xcodeproj` file only. You need to zip the entire project folder.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Here's the whole project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_35g5GvzjT8ZU9vVlVSbXg1eFk  Thanks.

Comment: @W.Cook, I have fixed your issue now. There was a few thing I fixed, but the main issue was that you needed to drag the segue from the viewController instead of the create button. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dtn0g7v2bo8tpy/Model%20Railroad%20Layout%20Pro.zip?dl=0) is an updated project that you can continue your work with. IIf my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Comment: Yes it did!  Sorry about that.  Two questions: is the navigation controller on the "Main View Controller" necessary, per the warning message? Or would a Navigation Bar do the same?  Also, what other changes did you make besides the segue?  Thanks.